# jQuery hover enlarge on wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've got this Wordpress plugin called Videogall that creates a gallery of thumbnails for Youtube videos that open in a Shadowbox when clicked. When you hover over a thumbnail in the gallery, the following code causes all the thumbnails *not* being hovered over to become more transparent.

```
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb').hover(function() {
    var currThumb = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb[id!="' + currThumb +'"]').stop().animate({opacity: 0.3}, 800);
}, function() {
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 800);
}
);
```

What can I add to this to make the image being hovered over also enlarge, a la hoverpulse (http://jquery.malsup.com/hoverpulse/)

Comment: HAve you seen this question of yours on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54645/29140? Why don't you create an account?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb').hover(function() {
    var currThumb = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb[id!="' + currThumb +'"]').stop().animate({opacity: 0.3}, 800);

    //added lines
    jQuery(this).css('width', jQuery(this).css('width') * 1.5);
    jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(this).css('height') * 1.5);

}, function() {
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 800);
}
);
```

This assumes the thumbnails have a width and height specified in CSS (by you or the plugin that makes them).

Answer (score 0):

This line of code matches ids of thumbnails that aren't being hovered over:

```
jQuery('.videogall-thumb[id!="' + currThumb +'"]').stop().animate({opacity: 0.3}, 800);
```

should it be changed to

```
jQuery('.videogall-thumb[id="' + currThumb +'"]').stop().animate({opacity: 0.3}, 800);

id=currThumb instead of id!=currThumb
```

Hope that helps.